# REACTjs - How to track if user reaches bottom of the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to track it so that when they reached bottom of the screen, i will call a function to fetch more data.
I have an app.js where inside is Products / component wherein it fetches data.
Products / is wrapped by a div.gallery container

I already used Intersection Observer but still fails, but maybe i used it wrong.

Comment: Easiest way for you is to use existing package. Similar to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component
Its quick to implement and they are well tested.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const container = document.getElementsByTagName(“body”);

function loadImages(numImages = 10)
{
   let i = 0;
   while(i < numImages)
   {
     fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
        const img =  document.createElement('img');
        img.src = `${data.message}`
        container.appendChild(img)
      })
      i++;
   }   
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if(window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight)
    { loadImages(); }
})
```

Credit: [Educative.io](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-implement-infinite-scrolling-in-javascript)

Comment: I chose to give this answer for posterity sake irrespective of the [`reactjs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs]) tag. This will be helpful to any user making use of a sane :) JavaScript library which recognizes the `window` object and it’s attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-intersection-observer` and you can implement it like this.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

const MainComponent = () => {
  const { ref, inView } = useInView();

  useEffect(() => {
     if (inView) { fetchMoreData() }
  }, [inView])

  return (
     <div className="container">
        <div>{renderYourListHere()}</div>
        <div ref={ref} />
     </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntersectionObserver like this, Whenever the end element is visible it'll trigger a callback. You can perform any action you want inside the callback.

```js
// Create list
const listItems = Array(100).fill(0);
const list = document.querySelector("#list");
listItems.forEach((item, i) => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = "item " + i;
  list.appendChild(li);
});


// Add intersection Observer
let options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 1,
};

const callback = (entries) => {
  const isVisible = entries[0].isIntersecting;
  if (isVisible) {
    console.log('End Element is Visible =>');
  }
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
observer.observe(document.querySelector("#end"));
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
<div id="end">END</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try plugins for "Infinite scroll", how it works is you can either choose the scroll of whole page or any parent division you want to.

If you want to implement it manually,

```js
const handleScroll = () => {
  if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight || isLoading) {
    return;
  }
  fetchData();
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}, [isLoading]);
```

You can try above [Refer it here](https://blog.logrocket.com/3-ways-implement-infinite-scroll-react/)

For the npm package suggestions,

[react-infinite-scroller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller)

[react-infinite-scroll-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component)